# Is it possible to make Jinja/Flask render code from text?

Tags: flask, jinja2

There is a `string` containing the following:

```
{% for something in listOfSomething %}
    ....
{% endfor %}
```

One of the lines in a template loads it using `{{ string }}`. However, it renders the text as a string, doesn't run the code.

Is there a way to run it in spite of it being string?

If so, how do you do that? I have never managed to find this in Jinja or Flask documentation.

Comment: The form is only rendered once. In your case when it loads {{ string }}. It does not re-render afterwards based on new code that was populated in the form.